# Designing a JVM REPL

Tags: java, class, jvm

I'm making a REPL for a simple made-up JVM language and I wanted to ask if anyone knows of a better design than the one I've currently come up with.

- Currently my made-up language generates a **new class file for every** line executed in the REPL.
- Each new class file has the same name and replaces the class file generated by running the previous line.
- My made-up language doesn't require code to be executed inside of a 'main' function, when generating the class file all of the code is inserted inside a main function because the JVM requires this.

Because my REPL generates a new class file for each line it executes, I can't maintain state between each line. For example:

```
>> a = 123; print a
```

This code works as expected because both statements are on the same line and will therefore be in the class file.

```
>> a = 123;
>> print a
```

This code won't work because the class file with 'print a' in it, doesn't have the instructions for 'a = 123'.

My current workaround for this is to store each variable in the symbol table (which persists between classes) and if I see 'print a' and 'a' is in the symbol table, then I insert the instructions for 'a = 123' before 'print a', to make sure the code runs.

I do it this way so that each instruction is being executed by the JVM directly and no instructions have to be interpreted by a Java program on top of the JVM, for performance. I think executing directly will have more benefits for loops or functions rather than variables.

Please let me know if I haven't explained anything clearly.

Comment: What is your _reason_ for writing this REPL?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I'm making a made-up JVM language as a cool project that will help me learn more about Java and the JVM.

Comment: In that case you might be interested in taking a look at BeanShell and groovysh. They're probably a lot more complicated than what you're working on but might give you some ideas on how to organize your system.